# phpmyadmin username and password

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin 5.1.36 through wampserver in my windows system. when i give http://localhost/phpmyadmin it directly gone into, showing databases what i did is i changed the password for the username root and phpmyadmin showed a message password successfully changed when i refresh the page it showed error

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What i expect is the page which is asking for username and password. What should be done to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking your config file; there should be a line that says `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']`. This should be set to either `cookie` or `http` if you want the username and password to be entered via login form.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change phpmyadmin's configuration to use your new root account password. Since you change the mysql root user password, phpmyadmin can no longer log into the database, and is now essentially dead until you update its configuration file with the new password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this behavior in the [PMA's config.inc.php](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php). You will need to set the auth_type to HTTP.